Angular i18n set locales
According to Angular doc about i18n, I set i18n options like this:

And set localize property inside build property to use "it-IT"

When I start application with "ng serve" command or run "ng build --localize" command I get the following warning:

I tried to import "it" locals data like "fr" example in Angular doc in file main.js, but warning still there.
I'd like to resolve this warning, and I think I followed the documentation correctly.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

where are you import the import '@angular/common/locales/global/it';? (see that different version of angular change the direction, e.g. in Angular 9 are in @angular/common/locales/it';, are you add "@angular/localize": in the package.json?

@Eliseo, I import it from import '@angular/common/locales/global/it'; inside main.ts file, where the doc say to import. I'm using Angular 17. And yes, I added @angular/localize package

in i18n options
try "sourceLocale": "en",
instead of "sourceLocale": "en-US"

I know that "workaround" to avoid the warning, but documentation says to use locale and localization information (so, "en-US" or "it-IT"). So, I don't understand why if I use "it-IT", Angular cli give me that warning... I can't figured out reading the documentation

There is a small typo in "instead"
